# Using multi streams in cuda graph, the execution order is uncontrolled

Tags: cuda, scheduling, cuda-streams, cuda-graphs

I am using cuda graph stream capture API to implement a small demo with multi streams. Referenced by the CUDA Programming Guide [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#cross-stream-dependencies), I wrote the complete code. In my knowledge, kernelB should execute on stream1, but with nsys I found kernelB is executed on a complete new stream. It is under-control. The scheduling graph is showed below:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

__global__ void kernelA() {}
__global__ void kernelB() {}
__global__ void kernelC() {}

int main() {
  cudaStream_t stream1, stream2;
  cudaStreamCreate(&stream1);
  cudaStreamCreate(&stream2);

  cudaGraphExec_t graphExec = NULL;
  cudaEvent_t event1, event2;
  cudaEventCreate(&event1);
  cudaEventCreate(&event2);

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    cudaGraph_t graph;
    cudaGraphExecUpdateResult updateResult;
    cudaGraphNode_t errorNode;
    cudaStreamBeginCapture(stream1, cudaStreamCaptureModeGlobal);
    kernelA<<<512, 512, 0, stream1>>>();
    cudaEventRecord(event1, stream1);
    cudaStreamWaitEvent(stream2, event1, 0);
    kernelB<<<256, 512, 0, stream1>>>();
    kernelC<<<16, 512, 0, stream2>>>();
    cudaEventRecord(event2, stream2);
    cudaStreamWaitEvent(stream1, event2, 0);
    cudaStreamEndCapture(stream1, &graph);
    if (graphExec != NULL) {
      cudaGraphExecUpdate(graphExec, graph, &errorNode, &updateResult);
    }
    if (graphExec == NULL || updateResult != cudaGraphExecUpdateSuccess) {
      if (graphExec != NULL) {
        cudaGraphExecDestroy(graphExec);
      }
      cudaGraphInstantiate(&graphExec, graph, NULL, NULL, 0);
    }
    cudaGraphDestroy(graph);
    cudaGraphLaunch(graphExec, stream1);
    cudaStreamSynchronize(stream1);
  }
}
```

Comment: The graph stores dependencies between the kernels and executes them accordingly. The dependency "B after A, C after A" seems to be respected so its ok. The streams used by the captured graph when executed may also differ from the streams the graph was captured on.

Comment: Oh, thanks, so I can not control this behavior to make it run on the stream I wanted right? I am wondering if there is some api I don't know to control this.

Comment: Why do you need a specific stream? Is something running on this stream on execution time of the graph?

Comment: @Sebastian,  I want to do some experiments on combining kernels with different streams to accelerate the whole performance, especially in deep learning. So I have to control the scheduling of kernel in each streams. CUDA Graph is useful for reducing the CPU overhead but it is under-control which confused me a lot.

Comment: Yes, but why specific streams? Or can the streams be renamed/renumbered, but the distribution on streams should be the same? In the original run you had kernel A and B on one and stream C on the other stream, now B and C are exchanged, but so late that it makes no difference?

Comment: The stream can be renamed, but the nsys graph showed above seems the distribution is not the same. Stream1 should have kernelA and kernelB but is kernelA and kernelC now. I don't think it makes no difference, for the overhead of kernelB and kernelC are different.

Comment: Would it be faster with manual control? I think that with replaying graphs it is like a pool of streams, as the graph takes control of sequencing.

Comment: I am just exploring whether manual control will be faster. You mean cuda graph will automatically do the runtime cost analyze for me?

Answer (score 2):

"An operation may be scheduled at any time once the nodes on which it depends are complete. Scheduling is left up to the CUDA system." [Here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#:%7E:text=An%20operation%20may%20be%20scheduled%20at%20any%20time%20once%20the%20nodes%20on%20which%20it%20depends%20are%20complete.%20Scheduling%20is%20left%20up%20to%20the%20CUDA%20system.).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I also ask in Nvidia Forums, Robert answered this question which help me a lot. Someone who are interested in the scheduling of cuda graph can also reference to this answer [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/using-multi-streams-in-cuda-graph-the-execution-order-is-uncontrolled/214672/4).